# Run a form in another thread

Tags: c#, forms, multithreading

i have five forms in my c# project. one host an httplistener that i want to run continionsly. when the listener gets a message, it passes it to a static class, which in turn calls the appropriate forms for another processing.

is it possible that the static class calls the new form in a new thread? if so please help me out

Comment: What kind of forms? Windows Forms? Web Forms? WPF Forms? Tax Forms?

Comment: Only play with controls on the primary form thread -- this holds true for WinForms and WPF (and Swing, actually); marshal to the correct thread as needed (see answers). Willy-nilly access will generally result in "cross-threading" exceptions and other "bad stuff".

Comment: am using vs2005, and am calling winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the forms should only deal with the visual aspects of the form.  Anything else,especially http listeners, should be handled with separate classes running on background threads.

Comment: @Smith: are you asking about running background threads, or your http listener on one?

Comment: This is what i want to do

"should be handled with separate classes running on background threads."

Answer (score 1):

"Calling a form" doesn't mean anything, I guess you'd only want to Show() it.  Creating a form on a worker thread is *never* a good idea.  Even if you do get the thread state right (STA and message loop), you'll have hard-to-solve Z-order and modality problems.

Simply use Control.Invoke to run code on the UI thread.  It should create the form and call its Show() method.

Comment: Additional note: There is also SychronizationContext and friends which are sometimes useful.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans said, it may not be recommended, but if necessary, you can call `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()` from any thread.  Just be careful and know what you are doing, if you do.